# How to transfer POSIXct data with multipel variables into time series format

Tags: r, time-series, posixct

I have data with multiple variables. The `str` of my data is as follows:

```
 tibble [2,859 × 92] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  $ Date             : POSIXct[1:2859], format: "2010-04-01" "2010-04- 
 02" "2010-04-05" "2010-04-06" ...
   $ Num              : num [1:2859] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  $ Price      : num [1:2859] 3158 3158 3159 3148 3119 ... `
```

I would like to transfer the data into a time-series format. I tried some solutions but did not work (e.g., [How can I transform a dataframe with POSIXct dates into a time series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473297/how-can-i-transform-a-dataframe-with-posixct-dates-into-a-time-series) I got this error:  `DF <- data.frame(FinDat = date, FinDat$Price = sample(100, length(date), TRUE)) Error: unexpected '=' in "DF <- data.frame(FinDat = date, FinDat$Price ="`)

An example of my data is:

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c(1270080000, 1270166400, 1270425600, 
 1270512000, 1270598400, 1270684800, 1270771200, 1271030400, 1271116800, 
 1271203200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
Price = c(3157.957, 3157.957, 3158.681, 3148.222, 3118.709, 
3145.347, 3129.263, 3161.251, 3166.183, 3164.966)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**I would like to use `autoplot` function and `auto.arima`**

Comment: *"into a time-series format"* could be several things depending on the packages/functions you intend to use. *"tried some solutions but did not work"* does not help us help you fix your code. Please include the code you've tried so we can help you fix it.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks a lot for your comment. It improves my question.

Comment: While the error is clear (don't use `FinDat$Price = ...` *inside* of `data.frame`), I think it would be good to see what you tried.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for in terms of output but this will convert it to a zoo series: `library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(dat)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  Thanks a lot for your help. I just would like to plot the data using `autoplot` and fit the Arima model to it.

Comment: @r2evans, I tried your suggestion, however, I got this error. `Error: unexpected '=' in "DF <- data.frame(FinDat$Date ="` I tried to not use `FinDat$Date` but got another error `DF <- data.frame(Date = date, Price = sample(100, length(date), TRUE))
Error in data.frame(Date = date, Price = sample(100, length(date), TRUE)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1`.

Comment: I can come up with no value of `date` where I see your second error.

Comment: This code works with the reproducible example in the question. Obviously if you change the nature of the data you will be introducing errors  into the working code and need to make corresponding changes.  That is why reproducible examples are required in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment the poster indicated that they want to plot the series and use arima (which uses ts) so we need to convert it to a regularly spaced series.  Convert it to zoo and then convert the times to year + fraction where fraction = 0, 1/N, 2/N, ..., (N-1)/N where N is the maximum number of points per year giving tt.  We can use that with arima.  We will need to have at least 2 years worth of data to perform certain analyses although the code below will work with less.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dat)
plot(z)  # or use autoplot(z) with ggplot2 or xyplot(z) with lattice

zz <- z   
yr <- as.integer(as.yearmon(time(zz)))
N <- max(table(yr))
time(zz) <- yr + (ave(yr, yr, FUN = seq_along) - 1) / N
tt <- as.ts(zz)

tt
## Time Series:
## Start = c(2010, 1) 
## End = c(2010, 10) 
## Frequency = 10 
##  [1] 3157.957 3157.957 3158.681 3148.222 3118.709 3145.347 3129.263 3161.251
##  [9] 3166.183 3164.966
```

[image: screenshot]